# iOS app crash on locale change

Tags: iphone, ipad, localization, crash, iso

When I leave my app, goto the settings and changes the language on the phone, my app (still resident in the background) crashes. 
Is there an interface or something that I should be implementing or is this expected behaviour?

The code that I'm using is very simple, really just one xib, localized to english and french.
There is no crash log that is product, but the console outputs the following:

```
May 29 12:08:30 unknown SpringBoard[1723] <Warning>: Killing <SBApplication: 0x1f57d320> com.MightyZeppelin.LocalizediPhone  activate:  deactivate:  for app installation
May 29 12:08:31 unknown SpringBoard[1723] <Warning>: Reloading application state for 'com.MightyZeppelin.LocalizediPhone' as its modification date has changed
May 29 12:08:32 unknown SpringBoard[1723] <Warning>: Reloading and rendering all application icons.
May 29 12:08:35 unknown com.apple.debugserver-50[1755] <Warning>: debugserver-50 for armv6 Copyright (c) 2007-2009 Apple, Inc.  All Rights Reserved.
May 29 12:08:35 unknown com.apple.debugserver-50[1755] <Warning>: Connecting to com.apple.debugserver service...
May 29 12:08:35 unknown kernel[0] <Debug>: lockbot[1747] Builtin profile: debugserver (sandbox)
May 29 12:08:35 unknown SpringBoard[1723] <Notice>: MultitouchHID(1f513310) uilock state: 1 -> 0
May 29 12:08:35 unknown MobileStorageMounter[1756] <Notice>: (0x3f4dd48c) platform_supports_camera_import: Platform is NOT configured for camera import
May 29 12:08:36 unknown com.apple.launchd[1] <Warning>: (UIKitApplication:com.MightyZeppelin.LocalizediPhone[0x47f]) Spawned and waiting for the debugger to attach before continuing...
May 29 12:08:36 unknown com.apple.debugserver-50[1755] <Warning>: Got a connection, waiting for debugger instructions for task "(null)".
May 29 12:08:36 unknown kernel[0] <Debug>: launchd[1757] Builtin profile: container (sandbox)
May 29 12:08:36 unknown kernel[0] <Debug>: launchd[1757] Container: /private/var/mobile/Applications/D0AA4DB0-9D85-4C7B-84EF-938C8C8DC952 [69] (sandbox)
May 29 12:08:45 unknown MobileStorageMounter[1756] <Notice>: (0x3f4dd48c) idle_timer_callback: Exiting after idle timeout
May 29 12:08:54 unknown Preferences[1758] <Warning>: BTM: attaching to BTServer
May 29 12:08:55 unknown Preferences[1758] <Warning>: BTM: posting notification BluetoothAvailabilityChangedNotification
May 29 12:09:04 unknown com.apple.SpringBoard[1723] <Notice>: CoreAnimation: timed out fence 5
May 29 12:09:05 unknown SpringBoard[1723] <Warning>: Preferred language has changed from 'en' to 'fr'. Relaunching.
May 29 12:09:05 unknown com.apple.launchd[1] <Warning>: (com.apple.mediaserverd) Exited with exit code: 254
May 29 12:09:05 unknown kernel[0] <Debug>: launchd[1760] Builtin profile: iapd (sandbox)
May 29 12:09:09 unknown MobileMusicPlayer[1766] <Warning>: ITDBPrepServerPostProcessRun: [BEGIN] looking up itdbprepserver.
May 29 12:09:09 unknown itdbprepserver[1767] <Warning>: starting up.
May 29 12:09:09 unknown itdbprepserver[1767] <Warning>: acquired iTunes sync file lock.
May 29 12:09:09 unknown itdbprepserver[1767] <Warning>: acquired itdbprep file lock.
May 29 12:09:09 unknown itdbprepserver[1767] <Warning>: posting com.apple.itdbprep.notification.willBegin
May 29 12:09:10 unknown MobileMusicPlayer[1766] <Warning>: ITDBPrepServerPostProcessRun: [-END-] looking up itdbprepserver.  success = 1
May 29 12:09:10 unknown itdbprepserver[1767] <Warning>: BEGIN processing command: com.apple.itdprep.command.runPostProcess
May 29 12:09:10 unknown MobileMusicPlayer[1766] <Warning>: *** MLSSqliteVFS AllWrites DISABLED ***
May 29 12:09:10 unknown itdbprepserver[1767] <Warning>: [BEGIN] ITDBPostProcessController...
May 29 12:09:11 unknown com.apple.launchd[1] <Notice>: (UIKitApplication:com.apple.mobileipod[0x83e4]) Exited: Killed: 9
May 29 12:09:12 unknown kernel[0] <Debug>: IOReturn IOMobileFramebufferUserClient::set_hotplug_notify(void*, void*) 0 0
May 29 12:09:12 unknown kernel[0] <Debug>: IOReturn IOMobileFramebufferUserClient::set_hotplug_notify(void*, void*) 0 0
May 29 12:09:13 unknown SpringBoard[1770] <Error>: WiFi: Consulting "no-sdio-devices" property.
May 29 12:09:13 unknown SpringBoard[1770] <Error>: WiFi: "no-sdio-devices" property not found.
May 29 12:09:13 unknown SpringBoard[1770] <Warning>: lockdown says the device is: [WildcardActivated], state is 3
May 29 12:09:13 unknown SpringBoard[1770] <Warning>: lockdown says we've previously registered: [1], state is 1
May 29 12:09:13 unknown SpringBoard[1770] <Notice>: CLTM: initial thermal level is 0
May 29 12:09:13 unknown SpringBoard[1770] <Notice>: MultitouchHID(1dd35200) uilock state: 1 -> 0
May 29 12:09:13 unknown locationd[22] <Error>: hidd died. Reestablishing connection.
May 29 12:09:14 unknown misd[1771] <Notice>: port forwarding is allowed
May 29 12:09:14 unknown misd[1771] <Info>: checking for carrier provisioning
May 29 12:09:14 unknown misd[1771] <Info>: carrier service is available
May 29 12:09:14 unknown misd[1771] <Debug>: published changes: success
May 29 12:09:14 unknown misd[1771] <Info>: maximum number of wireless tethered hosts is 5
May 29 12:09:14 unknown misd[1771] <Debug>: published changes: success
May 29 12:09:14 unknown misd[1771] <Debug>: attached to SpringBoard (0x1ed31140, port 0x3f0b)
May 29 12:09:14 unknown misd[1771] <Debug>: detached from SpringBoard (0x1ed31140, port 0x1ed31180)
May 29 12:09:14 unknown misd[1771] <Debug>: no clients left; resuming idle timer
May 29 12:09:14 unknown com.apple.launchd[1] <Warning>: (UIKitApplication:com.MightyZeppelin.LocalizediPhone[0x47f]) Exit timeout elapsed (1 seconds). Killing
May 29 12:09:17 unknown SpringBoard[1770] <Warning>: BTM: attaching to BTServer
May 29 12:09:19 unknown com.apple.launchd[1] <Warning>: (UIKitApplication:com.MightyZeppelin.LocalizediPhone[0x47f]) Did not die after sending SIGKILL 5 seconds ago...
May 29 12:09:21 unknown SpringBoard[1770] <Warning>: ITDBPrepServerPostProcessRun: [BEGIN] looking up itdbprepserver.
May 29 12:09:21 unknown itdbprepserver[1767] <Warning>: CPDistributedMessagingCenter ignoring message named com.apple.itdprep.command.runPostProcess since no target and selector are registered
May 29 12:09:21 unknown SpringBoard[1770] <Warning>: ITDBPrepServerPostProcessRun: [-END-] looking up itdbprepserver.  success = 0
May 29 12:09:23 unknown com.apple.launchd[1] <Warning>: (com.apple.AddressBook) Throttling respawn: Will start in 10 seconds
May 29 12:09:24 unknown com.apple.launchd[1] <Warning>: (UIKitApplication:com.MightyZeppelin.LocalizediPhone[0x47f]) Did not die after sending SIGKILL 10 seconds ago...
May 29 12:09:25 unknown com.apple.launchd[1] <Notice>: (UIKitApplication:com.MightyZeppelin.LocalizediPhone[0x47f]) Bug: launchd_core_logic.c:3794 (24506):3
May 29 12:09:25 unknown com.apple.launchd[1] <Notice>: (UIKitApplication:com.MightyZeppelin.LocalizediPhone[0x47f]) Bug: launchd_core_logic.c:3202 (24506):10
May 29 12:09:25 unknown com.apple.launchd[1] <Notice>: (UIKitApplication:com.MightyZeppelin.LocalizediPhone[0x47f]) Working around 5020256. Assuming the job crashed.
May 29 12:09:28 unknown MobileStorageMounter[1775] <Notice>: (0x3f4dd48c) platform_supports_camera_import: Platform is NOT configured for camera import
May 29 12:09:28 unknown SpringBoard[1770] <Warning>: Could not find mapped image Black_CARRIER_FIDO.png
May 29 12:09:28 unknown SpringBoard[1770] <Debug>: spd:_libspd_initialize_protocol:142 Registered notification port with spd [PID=1776]
May 29 12:09:28 unknown SpringBoard[1770] <Debug>: spd:_libspd_initialize_notify:241 All set up for spd wake notifications
May 29 12:09:29 unknown misd[1771] <Debug>: attached to SpringBoard (0x1ed30f30, port 0x3f17)
May 29 12:09:29 unknown misd[1771] <Debug>: detached from SpringBoard (0x1ed30f30, port 0x1ed30f70)
May 29 12:09:29 unknown misd[1771] <Debug>: no clients left; resuming idle timer
May 29 12:09:29 unknown SpringBoard[1770] <Warning>: BTM: posting notification BluetoothAvailabilityChangedNotification
May 29 12:09:30 unknown com.apple.printd[1777] <Notice>: Accepted connection from localhost:631 (Domain)
May 29 12:09:30 unknown com.apple.printd[1777] <Notice>: Closing connection from localhost:631 (Domain)
May 29 12:09:30 unknown SpringBoard[1770] <Error>: mms: ***** isMmsConfigured = 1
May 29 12:09:30 unknown SpringBoard[1770] <Warning>: BTM: BTLocalDeviceGetPairedDevices returned 0 devices
May 29 12:09:30 unknown com.apple.printd[1777] <Notice>: Accepted connection from localhost:631 (Domain)
May 29 12:09:30 unknown searchd[1779] <Warning>: Opened updates file at /var/mobile/Library/Spotlight/com.apple.MobileSMS/updates.SMSSearch.spotlight
May 29 12:09:30 unknown SpringBoard[1770] <Error>: WiFi: Consulting "no-sdio-devices" property.
May 29 12:09:30 unknown SpringBoard[1770] <Error>: WiFi: "no-sdio-devices" property not found.
May 29 12:09:31 unknown com.apple.printd[1777] <Notice>: Closing connection from localhost:631 (Domain)
May 29 12:09:32 unknown MobilePhone[1782] <Warning>: UI Mode is Phone
May 29 12:09:33 unknown com.apple.launchd[1] <Warning>: (com.apple.AddressBook) Throttling respawn: Will start in 10 seconds
May 29 12:09:33 unknown itdbprepserver[1767] <Warning>: Running Misc Commands...
May 29 12:09:33 unknown itdbprepserver[1767] <Warning>: Running Create Triggers...
May 29 12:09:33 unknown itdbprepserver[1767] <Warning>: Initializing MusicLibrary...
May 29 12:09:33 unknown itdbprepserver[1767] <Warning>: *** STARTING: DB Backup (CREATE-NEW) ***
May 29 12:09:33 unknown itdbprepserver[1767] <Warning>: *** FINISHED: DB Backup (CREATE-NEW, time = 0.13s) ***
May 29 12:09:33 unknown itdbprepserver[1767] <Warning>: [-END-] ITDBPostProcessController.
```

Comment: What does the crashlog look like? Maybe quoting it here would help.

Answer (score 3):

In all likelihood, the app probably doesn't crash. It gets killed by the operating system.

This is indeed expected behavior. All apps are killed on a language change, both on simulator and device.

Comment: Is this documented by Apple?